# How to constrain an auto increment (creating a calendar)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a table, which consist of following columns:

- `DateID`, which should start to count on 20130101. (1st JAN 2013) and end up at 20131231 (31st DEC 2013).
- `Year`, which has to stay 2013 (easy to handle by using VALUE).
- `Month`, which should start to count at 01 and ends up at 12.
- `Day`, which should start to count at 01 and ends up at 28, 30 and 31.

The auto increment has to consider the dependence on real dates.

More precisely:

The auto increment has to increase the ID by 1 and stops at 31 (31th JAN)

Then it should start to increase the month by 1.

After that it should switch again to the day and increase it by 1, till it reaches the 28th FEB.
Then it should start to increase the Month again ... and so on.

Of course it is quite the same for the "Month" column and for the "Day" column.

Is there any possibility to do something like that?

Comment: Why would you use auto increment on a calendar table? Make the primary key the date column (and use `DATE` as the data type). You will only need to populate this table once, the passage of time is predictable enough to insert all the dates you will ever need in one go, and you will never have to worry about inserting data to the table again

Comment: Alternatively, use a simple count and use `DateAdd()` to calculate the effective date from your base date.

Comment: You can store Datetime in one column and then extract Month, Year or Days from it when needed, to reduce the data redundcy when you want, what you are trying  to do is very BAD DATABASE MODEL.

Comment: In SQL Server **2012**, you could use a `SEQUENCE` which you can easily reset to 1 at any time needed, and get unique values from it when you insert a new row

Comment: @MuhammedAli It is not at all a very bad database model. [Calendar tables are very useful](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/), and can make some queries much more efficient, with very little space overhead

Comment: In some/very few cases if you have such requirements but generally speaking storing your data in one Column as Datetime and then Extratcing parts of datetime whenever whatever is needed.

Comment: @GarethD cheers pal it is a good read. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your hints.
@Muhammed Ali: Would you tell me how to do, what you suggested? Let's assume, I have a table, which has a column, called "DateReport", which has probably 50k rows. How do I extract the dates, which are stored as for instance "2013-04-04", and put them into a new table, called "MyDates", while spreading the year, month and day into different columns and order them by the dates of course?

Comment: is it "Date" datatype or VARCHAR ??

Comment: It is even DATETIME, therefore the date is like "2013-04-04 10:47:30.000".
Let me explain; I have a table, called "Incidents". Inside are many data stored, for instance the "IncidentID" and the "ReportingDate".
My intention was, to get all these dates and group them to see, how many "Incidents" were reported on day X; maybe in a month etc.
For me it isn't that interesting to see the hours, minutes and seconds. How do I do this? Could you show me a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE can do this for you:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
    isodate varchar(8),
    theyear int,
    themonth int,
    thedate int
);

WITH datecte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS cnt, CAST('1 Jan 1900' AS DATE) AS startdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cnt + 1, DATEADD(D, 1, startdate) 
        FROM datecte 
        WHERE DATEADD(D, 1, startdate) < '1 Jan 2000'
)
INSERT INTO @dates (isodate, theyear, themonth, thedate)
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), startdate, 112), 
            YEAR(startdate), 
            MONTH(startdate), 
            DAY(startdate)
        FROM datecte
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)


SELECT * FROM @dates
```

Comment: Not really an issue when only looping 365 times, but it is worth noting that using [a Recursive CTE is not an efficient way to generate a sequential list](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2). It is more verbose than many other methods so speed of writing is not really a reason to do it either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was quite the right answer I was searching for!

Comment: @GraethD - interesting, hadn't seen that before. Although if the goal is just pre-population of a calendar or numbers table any technique will achieve the goal, but yes it does show the fallacy of using them in "live" queries. The stacked CTE approach however looks interesting as it doesn't rely on system tables to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your base question, no, there's no way to "manipulate" auto-increment like that.  It can have a constant seed value and constant increment, but that's it.  You *could* manipulate it with an `INSERT` trigger that "resets" the increment seed, but I would not recommend it.

You don't need auto-increment - you can just compute the year, month, and day from the Date:

```
DECLARE @thedate DateTime
SELECT @thedate = GETDATE()  -- or whatever date you want to insert

INSERT INTO MyDates
([DateID], [Year],[Month], [Day])
VALUES (
    YEAR(@thedate)*10000 + MONTH(@thedate) * 100 + DAY(@thedate),               
    YEAR(@thedate),
    MONTH(@thedate),
    DAY(@thedate)
)
```

Now all you need is a loop to insert all the dates.

Comment: If you want a unique integer field in a Dates table, I'd recommend sequential numbers (e.g., `CAST(GETDATE() AS INT)`) rather than eight-digit numbers which aren't exactly human-readable but aren't comparable either.  With sequential numbers you can calculate `WHERE DatePaid > OrderDate + 30`, for example.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I'd agree, but there may be a valid reason for using the value the OP has - like joining to a legacy system that stores dates this way.

Comment: Absolutely, just an observation.  Of course you could also use both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive `CTE` to build this

```
WITH dates AS
(
    SELECT CAST('20130101' AS DATE) AS DateKey
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(D, 1, DateKey)
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATEADD(D, 1, DateKey) < '20140101'
)

SELECT DateKey, YEAR(DateKey) [Year], MONTH(DateKey) [Month], DAY(DateKey) [Day]
INTO Calendar
from dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT * FROM Calendar
```

Comment: Not really an issue when only looping 365 times, but it is worth noting that using [a Recursive CTE is not an efficient way to generate a sequential list](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2). It is more verbose than many other methods so speed of writing is not really a reason to do it either.